# what is a numpythonic way to create a matrix from two arrays without loops in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

suppose a 2D numpy array has to be created from two 1D numpy arrays x and y. The fortran pseudocode is as follows:

```
   do i = 1, n
   do j = 1, m
       A[i, j] = x[i]*y[j]
   enddo
   enddo
```

what is the most numpythonic way to create this 2D array this without using loops?

Comment: There is the [`np.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html#numpy.outer) function that does that. But using broadcasting as suggested in answer is also very *numpythonic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *numpythonic* way would be to use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

You can do a broadcasting operation if the dimensions of your arrays are compatible based on two criteria. Starting from the rightmost dimensions:

1. they are equal
2. they are 1.

If you want there to be length-x number of rows, you could to give it an appropriate dimension, with 1, for it to be broadcast with the `*` operation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y = np.array([10, 11])
>>> print(x[:, None] ,  y, sep="\n"*2)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]

[10 11]
>>> x[:, None] * y
array([[10, 11],
       [20, 22],
       [30, 33],
       [40, 44]])
```

Or using the other dimensions (corresponding to switching the orders of the loop):

```
>>> print(x , y[:, None], sep="\n"*2)
[1 2 3 4]

[[10]
 [11]]
>>> x * y[:, None]
array([[10, 20, 30, 40],
       [11, 22, 33, 44]])
```